# A Lebesgue Stieltjes integral where the integrator is a Lebesgue Stieltjes integral

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, stieltjes-integral

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel measurable and non-negative function; let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ have bounded variation but not necessarily be right-continuous. Then, the Lebesgue Stieltjes integral $$I(t) := \int_{(0,t]} f(u)  \mathrm{d}g(u)$$ is well defined for $t>0$.

Assume that $f,g$ are such that the integral $I$ has bounded variation. Let $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel measurable and non-negative function. My question: under which additional conditions on $f,g,h$ does the following identity hold $$\int_{(0,t]} h(u)  \mathrm{d} I(u) = \int_{(0,t]} h(u) f(u) \mathrm{d}g(u)?$$ Any help would be appreciated, including naming this identity so that I can better search for information. I have not made any progress on the problem.

Comment: I think it should always hold. This is just a special case of the more general result $\lambda(B) = \int_B \varphi(x)\,\mu(dx)$ and $f$ is integrable (or non-negative measurable) implies $\int_B f\,d\lambda = \int_B f(x)\varphi(x)\,\mu(dx)$. Just your standard 4 step argument.

Comment: Hi @AndrewZhang; thanks. I'm unfortunately not familiar with the 4 step argument. Could you please provide a reference? Are you referring to the sequence of arguments starting from indicators, considering bounded functions, etc?

Comment: Yes. See proposition 3.9 Folland Real Analysis 2e

Comment: Thanks @AndrewZhang: Could you please clarify how this problem can be formalized via Radon Nikodym derivatives?